Banach dual of the Hilbert-Schmidt operator

Let $T: L_2[0,1] \rightarrow L_2[0,1]$ be the Hilbert-Schmidt operator
corresponding to the kernel $K(x,y)$. That is, $$(Tf)(x) = \int_0^1 K(x,y)f(y) dy$$
Then, for the Banach duel $T^\star: L_2[0,1]^\star \rightarrow L_2[0,1]^\star$, we have $$(T^\star f)(x) = \int_0^1 \overline{K(y,x)} f(y) dy$$ under the
identification $L_2[0,1]^\star \equiv L_2[0,1]$.

This is an exercise in my notes (not for grades) that I am having trouble working out. I know that under Riesz, I can work instead with the Hilbert adjoint, and this becomes a consequence of Fubini’s theorem.
At the point this exercise was given, my class had not yet covered Hilbert duals, so I have been trying to show this directly. But I think the notation density has gotten a bit away from me, and I would like some help on working this out.

Not sure what can be used here. If you can’t use the fact that any Hilbert space is its own dual (technically, its complex conjugate is its dual), then can you use the fact that $L^p(\Omega)^\ast = L^q(\Omega)$ for measure spaces $\Omega$, where $1 < p,q < \infty$ and $1/p + 1/q = 1$?

Though technically the result is a bit weird. If we are actually working with dual spaces and the linear isomorphism $L^2(\Omega) = L^2(\Omega)^\ast$ (instead of the anti-linear isomorphism provided by Riesz), then there actually shouldn’t be that complex conjugate in the formula for $T^\ast$.

@DavidGao yes, I believe the idea is to work with the isomorphism between $L^2[0,1]^\star$ and $L^2[0,1]$ itself, i.e., identifying $x$ with $\langle \cdot, x\rangle$. Thinking about it more, I agree that the conjugate shouldn’t be there, since it’s the identification between $T^\star$ and $T’$ that introduces the complex conjugation as you said.

In that case, the result you want is also just Fubini. Apart from the issue that the complex conjugate shouldn’t be there, everything else is the same.
